# Cross-platform and good performance mobile application for iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone, mono, cordova, cross-platform

I need to develop an Application for both **iPhone** and **Android** platforms. I am looking for a cross-platform development frameworks. The important factors need to be taken into consideration are :

1. The App will be running in **intranet** environment (with **NO** internet
   connection).
2. **Drag and drop** features will be available in this App.
3. Needs to use the **barcode** reader library.
4. Needs to use **map** (it will probably be a custom map)
5. Receives **Push notifications** (currently I have mqtt in mind, since
   there is not internet connection)

If possible I only want to maintain only **one source code** for both platforms. I have done some research and I found 2 frameworks which are PhoneGap and Mono(touch and droid).

1. PhoneGap seems to be slow.
2. Mono need two code base for 2 platforms, only the libraries can be
   shared (correct me if I am wrong). This is my another worries about mono: http://redth.info/2010/04/09/is-monotouch-now-dead-in-the-water-what-does-apples-new-iphone-developer-agreement-mean

I know the native is the best but for the sake of maintenance and reusing our developer talent (which are C#, HTML, JavaScript) we need to find out the second best option.

Note : Please bear in mind the first 5 features listed on top for your answer.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
After exploring a few more tools, I like the performance of Appcelerator as well. But writing the whole app in JavaScript looks very messy to me and can't use OOP. And the extra package size  of (5~7 MB) is also something to take note for frequent releases environment. I like to hear from you guys as well.
 
 I will be updating our decision in coming few weeks.

Comment: You may be interested in this article: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2010/09/09/Apple-relaxing-SDK-license-agreement-MonoTouch-and-Flash-officially-allowed.aspx (a bit newer than one you linked).

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski If it is changed(restricted) again in the future, will I be able to use the one develop now?

Comment: I'd say: that's the riddle ;) It's quite stable for the time (both articles are a little bit old). I *think* their main purpose for such restrictions is that the user should not be able to install applications without AppStore. They can see web applications as a problem then, but programs built with Monotouch make them money on appstore just as the regular apps.

Answer (score 3):

This recent article [here](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2012/01/modern-cross-platform-development.html) may be helpful. It contains a rundown of several new cross platform mobile frameworks including [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/), [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/), [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/) and [Moai](http://getmoai.com/).

From reading your requirements I'd say that either MoSync or Titanium might be the best fit for you. Apart from PhoneGap, which is really just a web app running inside a mobile browser (and might be the reason you thought it was slow), they all generate native UI code apps.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying the MoSync now.

Answer (score 1):

go for http://www.appcelerator.com/

They first compile code in native code so performance is like native and they have barcode reader, push notification (via urban airship) too...

Comment: I don't think you'll get barcode reader and pushnotifiation in any other cross platform library

Comment: Thanks. How about the drag and drop and Map performance? Are they even doable?

Comment: yes.. maps are doable with appcelerator titanium and performance is good.. not sure what you mean by drag and drop

Comment: For example, in Android, I have two gridviews in a screen and the contents from one gridview cell should be able to copy by using drag and drop onto the other gridview cell.

Comment: The urban airship does not seem to have the in-house push mechanism (Note: I do not have access to internet).

Comment: yes they do not have in house push mechanism but they have urban airship module.. I have used UA in many project and it works great!

Comment: not sure about the drag and drop but I think this is also doable with titanium

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a hybrid application, using a mixture of native code and HTML5. Write native code for all the IO, and heavy lifting, and for the GUI use jQuery or similar in a web control embedded in your app. Android has a web control that allows you to interact with javascript. I assume you can do the same with Apple.  I'm trying to do something similar myself using Monodroid, and its looking very promising, although I discovered Monodroid does not have native Javascript interface yet.

Comment: I am also considering this as an option. But is it possible to catch the events raised from the HTML in the native code for both platforms?

Comment: Yes, see [iPhone UIWebView](http://connordenman.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/my-uiwebview-part-1-tutorial-8212-communication-between-objective-c-and-external-javascript-enjoy/) and [Android WebView addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: I have seen the links you provided. What I would like to do is - When I click a button on Webpage inside webview, instead of posting back to web server, I would like to raise the event to the native code and process it inside the native code.

Comment: Yes, thats the idea. I am waiting for Monodroid to have this feature. Not sure if Monotouch does this yet, but once thy both do it, it will be the ultimate in code reuse across both platforms and yet having full native control at the same time.

Comment: I didn't see that is even doable in native from the link you provided. How can it be done in Mono? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, we were using Appcelerator at my last company, and the performance for Android was less than desirable.  Our lead developer found the Mono products, and hasn't looked back.